# Multiple titles (suptitle) with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, subplot

I have a series of 9 subplots in a 3x3 grid, each subplot with a title. 
I want to add a title for each row. To do so I thought about using suptitle.
The problem is if I use 3 suptitles they seems to be overwritten and only the last one seems to be shown.

Here is my basic code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3,sharex='col', sharey='row')

for j in range(9):
    axes.flat[j].set_title('plot '+str(j))

plt1 = fig.suptitle("row 1",x=0.6,y=1.8,fontsize=18)
plt2 = fig.suptitle("row 2",x=0.6,y=1.2,fontsize=18)
plt3 = fig.suptitle("row 3",x=0.6,y=0.7,fontsize=18)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=1.1,top=1.6)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just `set_title` of axes 1, 4, 7 (`j%3 == 1`) and clear the rest?

Comment: Because I still need the title for every subplot, plus a title for the row

Comment: you can only have one `suptitle` per figure. I would suggest using `text` objects for the row titles

Comment: I think I will have to go with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tinker with the titles and labels. Check the following example adapted from your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3,sharex='col', sharey='row')

counter = 0
for j in range(9):
    if j in [0,3,6]:
        axes.flat[j].set_ylabel('Row '+str(counter), rotation=0, size='large',labelpad=40)
        axes.flat[j].set_title('plot '+str(j))
        counter = counter + 1
    if j in [0,1,2]:
        axes.flat[j].set_title('Column '+str(j)+'\n\nplot '+str(j))
    else:
        axes.flat[j].set_title('plot '+str(j))

plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: Row and Columns titles]

Comment: That's a good fix although given the length of my title not quite doable

Comment: @Alessandro You can manage the font size of labels to have something more well stored. The big problem with this method is if you want to give different formats to Columns and Titles for instance.

Comment: Unfortunately my subplots don't have a ylabel. I posted a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777296) to seek another workaround.