# Set multiple titles for a matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I'm creating subplots of venn diagrams that are made via [`matplotlib_venn`](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn). Here is the plot I'm making:

[image: Subplots missing top-right title]

Notice the missing title on the top-right plot. This is because whenever I call `ax.set_title`, it's replacing existing subplot titles. The code to create this plot was:

```
oadoi_colors = ['all', 'closed', 'closed + green', 'bronze', 'green', 'hybrid', 'gold']
collections = ['Combined', 'Crossref', 'Unpaywall', 'Web of Science']
figure, axes = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=len(oadoi_colors), ncols=len(collections), figsize=(2.7 * len(collections), 2.7 * len(oadoi_colors)))
subplot_label_rectprops = {'facecolor': '#fef2e2', 'boxstyle': 'round'}

for (oadoi_color, collection), df in coverage_df.groupby(['oadoi_color', 'collection']):
    i = oadoi_colors.index(oadoi_color)
    j = collections.index(collection)
    ax = axes[i, j]
    venn_plotter(df, ax=ax)
    if i == 0:
        text = ax.set_title(collection, loc='center', y=1.1)
        text.set_bbox(subplot_label_rectprops)
        # Top-right subplot cannot titled twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602347
    if j == len(collections) - 1:
        text = ax.set_title(oadoi_color.title(), x=1.1, y=0.5, verticalalignment='center', rotation=270)
        text.set_bbox(subplot_label_rectprops)
```

`venn_plotter` is a function that calls `matplotlib_venn.venn3_unweighted`. `df` is a `pandas.DataFrame` of the data.

In the matplotlib [title demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/titles_demo.html), it seems like you can set multiple titles... but I can't figure out how to do this with subplots.

There's an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602846/4651668) that suggests using `set_ylabel`. However, setting the ylabel has no effect on these venn plots.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that each axes subplots has exactly one title. If you call `set_title` a second time, the first title will be replaced.
There is not much of a difference between a title and a text. So you can decide to use titles for the columns and texts for the rows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        ax = axes[i,j]
        if i == 0:
            title = ax.set_title("column title", loc='center', y=1.1)
        if j == 2:
            text = ax.text(1.1,0.5,"row title", size=12,
                           verticalalignment='center', rotation=270)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note1: ax.text() is confined to its gridcell. If you truly want to annotate anywhere, multiple times, use plt.figtext(0.02, 0.5, 'mytext', fontsize=12, rotation=90)